Custom control doesn't capture value from bound property
I'm working on MAUI developing a custom control that shows Employee information based on its ID.
The custom control has the bindable property IdEmpleado defined as:
using MovilApp.Controls.ViewModel;

namespace MovilApp.Controls.Views;

public partial class InfoPanelView : ContentView 
{
    public InfoPanelViewModel LcViewModel { get; set; }

    #region Exposed Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Id del Empleado para desplegar sus valores
    /// </summary>
    public int IdEmpleado 
    {
        get => (int)GetValue(IdEmpleadoProperty); //I have a break point here...
        set => SetValue(IdEmpleadoProperty, value); //I have a break point here...
    }

    #endregion

    #region Bindable property fields

    public static readonly BindableProperty IdEmpleadoProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: nameof(IdEmpleado), returnType: typeof(int), declaringType: typeof(InfoPanelView),
        defaultValue: default, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: IdEmpleadoPropertyChanged);

    #endregion

    #region Callback methods

    private static void IdEmpleadoPropertyChanged(BindableObject pBindable, object pOldValue, object pNewValue) 
    {
        if (pOldValue == null || !pOldValue.Equals(pNewValue)) { //I have a break point here...
            ((InfoPanelView)pBindable).LcViewModel.LcModel.IdEmpleado = (int)pNewValue;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public InfoPanelView() 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LcViewModel = new InfoPanelViewModel();
        BindingContext = LcViewModel;
    }
}

And on the content page, I have this custom control set like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:panel="clr-namespace:MovilApp.Controls.Views"
    x:Class="MovilApp.Views.Equipos.EquiposView"
    xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:MovilApp.ViewModel.Equipos"
    Title="Asignación de Equipos">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <Model:EquiposViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Priority="0" Command="{Binding LcCommand}" >
            <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
                <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xe8b6;" FontFamily="MatlIconsRegular"
                    Color="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray200}}"/>
            </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        </ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <panel:InfoPanelView VerticalOptions="Start"
            BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference InfoPanelView}, Path=BindingContext}"
            IdEmpleado="{Binding LcModel.IdEmpleado}"/> <!-- This binding doesnt works, as it doesn't call the IdEmpleadoPropertyChangedMethod -->

        <Label Text="{Binding LcModel.IdEmpleado, StringFormat='IdEmpleado: {0}'}" /> <!-- This binding works, as i can see the value on the app screen -->

        <ListView RowHeight="1000" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray500}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding LcModel.Asignaciones}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <panel:EquipoPanelView
                        IdAsignacion="{Binding IdAsignacion}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </VerticalStackLayout>

</ContentPage>

This is how my APP shows.

Can you help me finding whats my problem is??
I will be very grateful to you
Regards!

your binding context is set to the VM, but your ID property is defined in the control itself.  Generally custom controls inherit their BindingContext from the parent, not from their own VM

Hi Jason... Yes, yesterday I realized that I can't use the MVVM Architecture Pattern inside a control because the ContentPage replaces the bindingcontext of the objects that are inside the page. However, although I have to change that part of the code, I'm not sure if that's my problem, since, when I set a value for IdEmpleado, in theory, it should execute at least the IdEmpleadoPropertyChanged method, and I don't see that it gets executed.

you are using two completely different binding contexts for IdEmpleado.  Why?

Damn... It was part of a test to see if I could force the VM assignment that I assumed was correct. Sorry, that's the problem, it works now. Thanks a lot... :(

Your InfoPanelView should not set/read BindingContext nor should it have a view model. If it's a reusable component, defining BindableProperty and keeping it loosely coupled would mean the component can be deployed anywhere. On the ContentPage, you are free to connect those BindableProperty to your view model, etc.

Thanks Stephen...

Did you solve your problem according to Stephen Quan's suggestion?

Yes... it works now.
